# Insert data on SQL

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2005, insert

I'm trying to insert data to my database on sql and after I run my program an error occured and says :

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

how can I fix it? can anyone tell me what is wrong with my codes?

here is the codes :

```
private void btnInsertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

        String url = "jdbc:odbc:****";
        String user = "****";
        String pass = "****";
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        String pIDNo = txtPatientID.getText();
        String pFName = txtpFName.getText();
        String pLName = txtpLName.getText();
        String pMI = txtpMI.getText();

        String sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Patients VALUES (" + 
                (pIDNo)+",'"+(pFName)+"','"+(pLName)+"','"+(pMI)+"')";
        statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Patient Added!");
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Here is the table info :

[image: PatientTable]

Comment: Can you share your table structure

Comment: What are your table col names and datatypes?

Comment: You have to mention the column names also before assigning the values in the query

Comment: are you sure pIDNo column of Patients table is String and not an unique id which is auto increment?.

Comment: actually sir subodh the table that your looking was made by my boss, he just asked me to do a program that can manipulate that thing so everything in that table is 'as is'.

Comment: @JibranKhan, that is not mandatory we have two option to insert values inside table by providing column name of table or without column name by providing values only.

Comment: @subodh, yes not neccessary but just to avoid any cause of error.

Comment: @CrystalMaiden, If you have access of database then see the table description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using implicit `INSERT` statement, the number of values supplied must be equal to the total cumber of columns in the table, eg

```
INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (val1, val2)
```

In the query above, the expected number of columns are two because you have supplied two values.

When there is an incrementing field, you must pass `null` value on it. But if not, you need to specify the column names for which the values will be inserted, eg

```
INSERT INTO tableName (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2)
```

As a side note, values must be parameterized to avoid from `sql injection`. See the article below:

- [Java PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

**UPDATE 1**

Specifying of columns names is required since you are not inserting values on all columns.

```
INSERT INTO Patients (pIDNo, pFName, pLName, pMI)
VALUES (...)
```

Comment: I will study the Java PreparedStatement thing, thanks! Glad to know that there is some PH here...

Comment: @CrystalMaiden hehe..hey what are the columns in your table `Patient`?

Comment: I post it above sir J W can you please take a look at it and tell me what is wrong?

Comment: I have created a program just like this but in different langauge. I see that it's the same as your update answer hmmm quite hard to do though, let me re-code my program and tell you what will happen sir JW.

Comment: String sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Patients" 
                + "(pIDNo,pLName,pFName,pMI)"
                + "VALUES()";

what is next after this?

Comment: `String sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Patients (pIDNo, pFName, pLName, pMI) VALUES (" + pIDNo + ",'" + pFName + "','" + pLName + "','" + pMI + "')";`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27524/discussion-between-crystal-maiden-and-j-w)

Answer (score 1):

What is the type of pIDNo, pFName, pLName, pMI?

Change type to varchar to receive text input.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound like newbie but I am, can you teach me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the ID field set to auto so should not be passing it in the insert? You should list the fields in the insert statement, e.g. INSERT INTO dbo.Patients(column1, column2...). See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp).